# como calcular días entre 2 fechas del mismo año en php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, date

tengo un problema que ojala me puedan ayudar.

Estoy intentando calcular los días entre 2 rangos de fechas 01/Enero al 31/Diciembre del año que algún usuario desee.

tengo esta consulta con PHP que si me da el resultado, pero cuando un registro esta en años diferentes en ingreso y salida por ejemplo (el registro 1) cuando el usuario seleccione el año 2020 me debe de decir que estuvo 3 días en el año 2020 y cuando el usuario seleccione 2021 me debe decir que estuvo 10 días.

la variable $year es el año que recibo cuando el usuario selecciona un año en especifico.

```
    SELECT Ingreso, Salida, Localidad,
           CASE 
             WHEN CAST(Salida AS date) < CAST('".$year."-12-31' AS date)
             THEN DATEDIFF (DAY, Ingreso, Salida) + 1
             WHEN CAST(Salida AS date) > CAST('".$year."-12-31' AS date)
             THEN DATEDIFF (DAY, Ingreso, '".$year."-12-31') + 1
           END AS Dias 
      FROM DT_ViajesUSA 
      WHERE UserName = '".$user."' 
       AND Ingreso BETWEEN '".$year."-01-01' AND '".$year."-12-31' 
      Group by Salida, Ingreso, Localidad 
      ORDER BY Ingreso DESC "
```

```
    mi base de datos esta así:

    | #  | usuario |   Ingreso  |   Salida   |  Localidad |
    -------------------------------------------------------
    | 1  | Jorge   | 2020-12-28 | 2021-01-10 |   México   |
    | 2  | Jorge   | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-10 |   México   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MySql

```
SET @YEAR = '2021';
SELECT Ingreso, Salida, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @year = YEAR(Ingreso)
         THEN abs(DATEDIFF ( Ingreso, CONCAT(YEAR(Ingreso),'-12-31')))
         WHEN @year = YEAR(Salida)
         THEN abs(DATEDIFF ( Salida, CONCAT(YEAR(Ingreso),'-12-31')) )
       END AS Dias 
  FROM fechas 
  WHERE nombre = 'Jorge' 
     AND Ingreso BETWEEN CONCAT(@YEAR,'-01-01') AND CONCAT(@YEAR,'-12-31') 
     OR Salida BETWEEN CONCAT(@YEAR,'-01-01') AND CONCAT(@YEAR,'-12-31') 
  Group by Salida, Ingreso 
  ORDER BY Ingreso DESC
```

He añadido el OR para que no elimine a los usuarios no ingresados en el año elegido (ingresado en el año anterior). Si cambias la variable @year por 2020  obtienes que el primer registro 3 días y 244 para el segundo. Si cojes 2021 tienes 10 días para el primer registro, el segundo no aparece.

¿Es esto lo que buscas?